# Calculate angle between two vectors (atan2 discontinuity issue)

Tags: c, matlab, math, vector, simulink

I have two vectors that I want to calculate the angle in between.

One vector is defined as two points say `P1(x1,y1)` and `P2(x2,y2)`. The other vector is defined as a point `P3(x3,y3)` and its heading angle with respect to x axis (say theta).

I know I need to get the product of them but but how to get the second vector in terms of two points?

Actually I have tried to use atan2(), however when the angle is around pi(+-epsilon), it makes jumps from pi to -pi, which is undesired and I cannot fix it simply by adding 2*pi when the angle is smaller than zero. My simulation becomes jumping from +pi to -pi in that case.

I am using `C-mex S-functions`, but any `pseudocode` would be okay as well.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need P3(x3,y3), angles simply add and subtract, so just take the difference between `theta` and the angle to the X axis for vector between P1 and P2. See http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-find-the-angle-and-magnitude-of-a-vector.html for worked-through example.

Comment: Sure, that was the first thing I have tried. However, the angle of the vector 1 as well as vector 2 can become PI radians. and the problem occurs there, since I am getting the angle of the first vector with atan(y,x), it has discontinuities and causes the problem, otherwise I know how to add and subtract angles.

Comment: Did you try anything? Do you just expect us to do your assignment for you?

Comment: Why are you using atan? Use atan2 if you want unambiguous angles.

Comment: I always read up [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/151925) discussion when I want to to understand how to calculate angle between two vectors.

Comment: I was using atan2, sorry for mistyping it as atan. And thanks for the link to matlabcentral, that is a similar issue to what I am having.

Furthermore, I am not expecting anyone to do an assignment and it is not an assignment at all. 

My problem occurs when the angle is around pi (found by atan2) it jumps to pi to -pi (discontinuity) and when I try to fix it simply by adding +2*pi when it is smaller than zero doesn't work well. I am editing the post above accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken entire stuff from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/151925). Please read the discussion there for understanding of this topic.

> Assuming a = [x1,y1] and b = [x2,y2] are two vectors with their bases at the 
>   origin, the non-negative angle between them measured counterclockwise 
>   from a to b is given by

```
angle = mod(atan2(x1*y2-x2*y1,x1*x2+y1*y2),2*pi);
```

for MATLAB implementation, `mod` can be replaced with `rem`:

```
angle = rem(atan2(x1*y2-x2*y1,x1*x2+y1*y2),2*pi);
```

> The quantities, x1*y2-x2*y1 and x1*x2+y1*y2 are, respectively, the sine and cosine of the counterclockwise angle from vector a to vector b, multiplied by the product of their norms - that is, their cross product and the dot product restricted to two dimensions. The 'atan2' function then gives the angle between them ranging from -pi to +pi, and the 'mod' operation changes this so as to range from 0 to 2*pi.

Please don't use formula such as `theta = acos(dot(a,b))` since it has accuracy issues near `pi` and `-pi`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was using a similar thing and thanks for the matlabcentral link. I have edited my question because I felt that I was not clear to define my question above. The problem arises when atan2 gives result around pi, since +-epsilon difference causes jumps of 2*pi magnitude which is undesired and I could not fix it by just adding +2*pi when it is smaller than zero.

Comment: And I don't have mod operation as in matlab, since I am using C. Would '% 2*pi' operation work the same as mentioned in your solution?

Comment: @birincilikteli please post whatever you had tried in the question by editing it, otherwise the question may get closed. I don't think it is such a bad question.

Comment: S: Chandakkar thank you for your help, and I have figured out the answer to my question in my mind. In any case I would need two normalized vectors and for vector 1 it is defined as two points which was clear. I was unclear about the second vector, but since I need the unit vector (not the length for the angle), it is (1*cos(theta), 1*sin(theta)) that passes through P3 and the rest is using the differences of angles calculated by atan2().